# How can I fix this SQL issue "Unknown column" for "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

```
INSERT INTO design_materials(`id`,`design_id`,`material`,`quantity`)
    VALUES(NULL, 11, '1', 3)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `design_id` = VALUES(`design_id`), 
                            `material` = VALUES(`material`), 
                            `quantity` = VALUES(`quantity`)
```

This is the error
*Unknown column 'design_materials.material' in 'where clause'*
All table column are correct as seen in the image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgR8e.jpg

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using -- which is presumably MySQL.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the table structure too as ascii text with sample data. It would be especially helpful if you could tell us which column is the primary key.

Comment: We can't see the image that you're referencing. Can you please update?

Comment: After restarting my system, I noticed the query worked fine as it should, could anyone explain why it had issue earlier?